# Email and database have different verification code

Tags: php, mysql

```
 // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err) && empty($mobile_err)){
        $ran_code=mt_rand(100000, 999999);
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, mobile, code) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :mobile, :code)";

        if($stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $param_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $param_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':mobile', $param_mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_mobile = $mobile;
            $code = $ran_code;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
              $_SESSION['username']=$email;
                // Send registration confirmation link (verify.php)
              $_SESSION['to']      = $email;
              $_SESSION['subject']  = 'Account Verification ( paper.com )';
              $_SESSION['body'] = '
              Hello '.$username.',

              Thank you for signing up!

              Your verification code is'.$ran_code.'.'; 


              require '../Mailer/hotmail.php';

                header("location:confirmation.php?email=".$email);


            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    unset($dbh);}
```

After successful registration, confirmation code gets sent to email and also stored in database. I get one set of 6 code in email and totally different 5 digit code in database.i have tried this more than 10 time and the result is the same. Every time i get new key in email where as in database the key is same  i.e 32767.
and also what i am doing is after registration i check my email and check database, the code is different then i delete the row and proceed to sign up again with same email address. i don't think this is the problem but just to let you guys know.

Comment: `32767` indicates some max value for int. What's the type of your `code`  field?

Comment: And unless you try to use values as numbers, define their types as __varchar__

Comment: Try running a raw query in Shell or in phpMyAdmin & check if you are getting the same result or not ! If you are so there may be something wrong with your data types..!

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are passing different values in both case

You got the random number

```
 $ran_code=mt_rand(100000, 999999);
```

But, you are saving to database something else

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
```

After above code, you have below line of code, which suppose to be above (Please note, in email you are using `$ran_code`, which has correct value)

```
 $code = $ran_code;
```

And, that is the reason you get different value in email and database. To correct your issue, you need to move above line of code just after

```
$ran_code=mt_rand(100000, 999999);
$code = $ran_code; // move here
```

Comment: you mean parameter should be set before binding values to prepared statement

Comment: you mean parameter should be set before binding values to prepared statement.1st if($stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql)){ 2nd $code = $ran_code;
3rd      $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);}

Comment: how come every time there is '32767' in the database. shouldn't the column be empty.

Comment: @makehappen2017 you need to atleast debug before you ask because I can't tell what exactly is your table design. But, as you mentioned everytime you are getting same value . That means new value is not getting inserted and that means table has some constraints may be on username and that is the reason it might be failing

Comment: @makehappen2017 you could use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` check google for its syntax

Comment: yeah i got it, the problem was the data type of code column in database. When i changed it from smallint(6) to int(6) everything is working fine. Why is smallint doing so?

Comment: @makehappen2017 You will get the answer here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html. Note, range matters. At the end, You need to upvote and mark accepted answer

Comment: @makehappen2017 You are suppose to **upvote and accept the answer** when you get solution. This is how stackoverflow works.

Comment: declaring variable before binding prompts an error, the correct way to declare it is after binding parameter. But if you are binding value it works as you mentioned above i.e to declare variable before binding happens. And i am not using Value to bind. And the problem lies in me making column small int but inserting value larger than supported by small int.

Comment: @makehappen2017 that shows you didn't debug and research your code

Comment: you should have got this, if you have debugged your code properly. If you still don't know what I meant then only god can help

Comment: i debugged it that's why i found i used wrong data type.

Comment: Yes of course, you debugged when I asked you. But, I was saying before you post any question you should properly debug your code and research your work.

Comment: If you will post question like that, then in future you won't get any solution/answer for your question. Also, make habit of accepting and upvoting answers.